# string to int the value got lost

Tags: c++, string, casting, int

I want to cast my string vector into int, but first I want to check if it is a integer or a float.

for example

```
   //private member h file
   unsigned int lemon; // cant write auto lemon so I cant check what type it is
   unsigned int sugar;
   unsigned int water;



  //method
  int class::name(std::vector<std::string> params)

    std::stringstream str0(params.at(1));

    str0 >>lemon;

    std::cout<<lemon<<std::endl;
```

now I want to check what inside the lemon is.
Now when i run in the main and write the following inputs

```
  3.2
```

it gives me

```
  3
```

When I check the params.at(1) it just give me back the input what I write before.

```
 3.2
```

Can someone tell me what went wrong and how can I check wheter the string is a float/double/int?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. Currently it isnt quite clear how that output comes from the code you provide

Comment: if you are not sure what would be the input, you can't even assume it's number at all.

Comment: Are you surprised to get `3` from `"3.2"` ? Or is it something else you're asking ?

Comment: You try to store a ```double``` into an ```int``` so you loose precision, ```3.2``` become ```3``` it is normal, use a ```double``` or ```float``` instead

Comment: why would an `int` ever give you `3.2`? that's blasphemy..

Comment: If your string contains `3.2` and you convert the string to int you get the integer part `3` it should work like that, but I believe that the problem is that when you come back to `main` you find that the value continues to be `3.2` and that may be because you [pass `lemon` by value instead pass it by reference...](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/)

Comment: ah i know my mistake... thanks everyone

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get exact input value (how it was provided by user), then use `string` for saving values.
If you need to save float values, then use type `double` for saving values.

Type `int` can save only integer values, like 3.

Answer (score -1):

When you extract an int from a stream with >>, it reads for as long as there are characters that could be considered part of an int. Integers do not allow for fractional parts, so there are no decimal points in int values.

You can either try parse as int and check if parsing used all input characters. Or parse as float and see if the result is fractional:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{

    unsigned int i;
    std::stringstream str0("3");
    std::stringstream str1("3.2");

    str0 >>i;
    std::cout << i << "  " << str0.eof() << std::endl;
    str1 >>i;
    std::cout << i << "  " << str1.eof() << std::endl;

    double d;
    std::stringstream str2("3");
    std::stringstream str3("3.2");

    str2 >>d;
    std::cout << d << "  " << (d == floor(d)) << std::endl;
    str3 >>d;
    std::cout << d << "  " << (d == floor(d)) << std::endl;

}
```

output:

```
3  1
3  0
3  1
3.2  0
```

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? Would the downvoter bother to explain the reasons?